# Postgres custom aggregation returns null when parallelized

Tags: postgresql, aggregation

I have created a custom aggregate in postgres 11.3 and it works when parallel if off. When I mark it as parallel = safe, it returns null.

Could someone point me in the direction of where to start looking or how do I debug a parallel aggregation in postgres? In non parallel aggregation I can insert the state at each record into a temporary table, but inserts are not allowed in parallel queries...

Here's the aggregate:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION array_sort(ANYARRAY)
RETURNS ANYARRAY LANGUAGE SQL
AS $$
SELECT ARRAY(SELECT unnest($1) ORDER BY 1)
$$;

create type _stats_agg_accum_type AS (
    cnt bigint,
    q double precision[],
    n double precision[],
    np  double precision[],
    dn  double precision[]
);

create type _stats_agg_result_type AS (
    count bigint,
    q25 double precision,
    q50 double precision,
    q75 double precision
);

create or replace function _stats_agg_p2_parabolic(_stats_agg_accum_type, double precision, double precision)
returns double precision AS '
DECLARE
    a alias for $1;
    i alias for $2;
    d alias for $3;
BEGIN
    RETURN a.q[i] + d / (a.n[i + 1] - a.n[i - 1]) * ((a.n[i] - a.n[i - 1] + d) * (a.q[i + 1] - a.q[i]) / (a.n[i + 1] - a.n[i]) + (a.n[i + 1] - a.n[i] - d) * (a.q[i] - a.q[i - 1]) / (a.n[i] - a.n[i - 1]));
END;
'
language plpgsql;

create or replace function _stats_agg_p2_linear(_stats_agg_accum_type, double precision, double precision)
returns double precision AS '
DECLARE
    a alias for $1;
    i alias for $2;
    d alias for $3;
BEGIN
    return a.q[i] + d * (a.q[i + d] - a.q[i]) / (a.n[i + d] - a.n[i]);
END;
'
language plpgsql;

create or replace function _stats_agg_accumulator(_stats_agg_accum_type, double precision)
returns _stats_agg_accum_type AS '
DECLARE
    a ALIAS FOR $1;
    x alias for $2;
    k int;
    d double precision;
    qp double precision;
BEGIN
    a.cnt = a.cnt + 1;

    if a.cnt <= 5 then
        a.q = array_append(a.q, x);
        if a.cnt = 5 then
            a.q = array_sort(a.q);
        end if;
        return a;
    end if;

    case
        when x < a.q[1] then
            a.q[1] = x;
            k = 1;
        when x >= a.q[1] and x < a.q[2] then
            k = 1;
        when x >= a.q[2] and x < a.q[3] then
            k = 2;
        when x >= a.q[3] and x < a.q[4] then
            k = 3;
        when x >= a.q[4] and x <= a.q[5] then
            k = 4;
        when x > a.q[5] then
            a.q[5] = x;
            k = 4;
    end case;

    for ii in 1..5 loop
        if ii > k then
            a.n[ii] = a.n[ii] + 1;
        end if;
        a.np[ii] = a.np[ii] + a.dn[ii];
    end loop;

    for ii in 2..4 loop
        d = a.np[ii] - a.n[ii];
        if (d >= 1 and a.n[ii+1] - a.n[ii] > 1) or (d <= -1 and a.n[ii-1] - a.n[ii] < -1) then
            d = sign(d);
            qp = _stats_agg_p2_parabolic(a, ii, d);
            if qp > a.q[ii-1] and qp < a.q[ii+1] then
                a.q[ii] = qp;
            else
                a.q[ii] = _stats_agg_p2_linear(a, ii, d);
            end if;
            a.n[ii] = a.n[ii] + d;
        end if;
    end loop;

    return a;
END;
'
language plpgsql;

create or replace function _stats_agg_combiner(_stats_agg_accum_type, _stats_agg_accum_type)
returns _stats_agg_accum_type AS '
DECLARE
    a alias for $1;
    b alias for $2;
    c _stats_agg_accum_type;
BEGIN
    c.cnt = a.cnt + b.cnt;
    c.q[2] = (a.q[2] + b.q[2]) / 2;
    c.q[3] = (a.q[3] + b.q[3]) / 2;
    c.q[4] = (a.q[4] + b.q[4]) / 2;
    RETURN c;
END;
'
strict language plpgsql;

create or replace function _stats_agg_finalizer(_stats_agg_accum_type)
returns _stats_agg_result_type AS '
BEGIN
    RETURN row(
        $1.cnt,
        $1.q[2],
        $1.q[3],
        $1.q[4]
    );
END;
'
language plpgsql;

create aggregate stats_agg(double precision) (
    sfunc = _stats_agg_accumulator,
    stype = _stats_agg_accum_type,
    finalfunc = _stats_agg_finalizer,
    combinefunc = _stats_agg_combiner,
    --parallel = safe,
    initcond = '(0, {}, "{1,2,3,4,5}", "{1,2,3,4,5}", "{0,0.25,0.5,0.75,1}")'
);
```

Here's the setup and run code:

```
--CREATE TABLE temp (val double precision);
--insert into temp (val) select i from generate_series(0, 150000) as t(i);
select (stats_agg(val)).* from temp;
```

The expected result as follows and it works when run in parallel = unsafe

```
150001, 37500, 75000, 112500
```

In parallel = safe I get nulls:

```
150001, null, null, null
```

Comment: It can be Postgres bug - please, report it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the `_stats_agg_combiner` function. The function definition includes the `strict` keyword so there is no need to check for null input values.

In this specific aggregate, the `_stats_agg_accum_type` includes multiple arrays and the `_stats_agg_combiner` function requires that these arrays be filled with a minimum of 5 entries. This assumes that each new `_stats_agg_accum_type` instance processes at a minimum 5 records before being passed to the `_stats_agg_combiner` function.

Tests were being done on a table with 150k records and an assumption that each instance would therefore receive at a minimum 5 records. For whatever reason, this is an incorrect assumption. Regardless of the number of workers used (tested with 1-4) there is always at least one instance which processed exactly 0 records.

The solution was to add support for a `_stats_agg_accum_type` instance that had processed zero records and this had an array length of 0. See code below.

```
create or replace function _stats_agg_combiner(_stats_agg_accum_type, _stats_agg_accum_type)
returns _stats_agg_accum_type AS '
DECLARE
    a alias for $1;
    b alias for $2;
    c _stats_agg_accum_type;
    addA boolean;
    addB boolean;
BEGIN
    addA = a.cnt <= 5;
    addB = b.cnt <= 5;
    if addA and not addB then
        c = b;
    elsif addB and not addA then
        c = a;
    else
        c.cnt = a.cnt + b.cnt;
        for ii in 2..4 loop
            c.q[ii] = (a.q[ii] + b.q[ii]) / 2;
        end loop;
    end if;
    for ii in 1..5 loop
        if addA and ii <= a.cnt then
            c = _stats_agg_accumulator(c, a.q[ii]);
        end if;
        if addB and ii <= b.cnt then
            c = _stats_agg_accumulator(c, b.q[ii]);
        end if;
    end loop;

    RETURN c;
END;
'
language plpgsql strict;
```